# Tensorflow body part recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a developer who is really interested in ML and using Tensorflow but despite all the tutorials I have gone through, I am really struggling to start building my own model and was hoping you guys can help answer some questions that might be pretty simple.

I am trying to build an algorithm that will detect specific points on a body (shoulders, wrists and others) from an image, however I am not sure what the output of the model should be, My training data is a set of images and a list of x,y values for the points and I am hoping to return a prediction for the location of the points on the image (similar to facial recognition).

But I have a few questions when building this:

1- What should the output of my application be? I want the algorithm to return the most likely x,y positions for each point but not sure how to represent that in tensorflow, do i need a large number of tensors in my output for each pixel and the correct pixels have a value of 1?

2- How can I deal with different size images, since the input tensor will have a predetermined number of features how can my algorithm accept any size image?

3- How do I determine if there are no valid points on the image? Is it just by including empty images in my training set?

I hope these questions make sense and I am thankful for whoever takes the time to read it! This would be a really big help for me understanding Tensorflow and making good progress in pursing my interest in ML!

Comment: I think stackoverflow is more for technical issues rather than overall questions about how to learn tensorflow.

Comment: https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5 This may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i wasn't sure where to post it @AlexisDrakopoulos

Comment: Thanks alot @EighteenthVariable Ill give it a look

Comment: No worries, Tensorflow has great documentation and also has a starter series on their youtube channel you can check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in various different ways and depends how you want to encode your data's semantics. I try to give a very simple example that may not have the best outcome:

1 - You can represent a human body pose as a list of vertices, which is a vector. This could be fore example:

```
[left_shoulder,
 right_shoulder,
 torso,
 ...]
```

Each vertex is a x, y tuple so your output dimension would be `[vertex_count, 2]` or `vertex_count * 2` (flattened version). The output would therefore be these x,y positions for each vertex. This is a regression problem, because your output tries to [generate continuous values](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141386/606315). You could also add a value for confidence of the recognized body pose. This would have the advantage to be able to not display/handle a pose if none is recognized and can work with a simple cutoff when interpreting your model's output.

2 - The easiest way to handle images of different size is an added preprocessing step: Simply resize the image to fit your trained model.

3 - Yes this could be a good starting point. Maybe also bodies that don't fit in the frame where it's hard to label.

The article on Medium shared by @EighteenthVariable is also a very good start to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you soooo much dude! This is really useful info! apprecaite it!

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this answers your question you can mark it as such.